# duplicate a collection onto vertex group

Tags: vertex-groups, geometry-nodes

I am so struggling on a duplication issue.
I want to duplicate a collection into some certain position, which is already define as vertex-group as shown below.

[image]

I try to use geometry node to achieve this. As shown my script.

[image]

Then something strange happed. As you can see that it duplicates, but the collection jump very far away from the target vertex group and scaled up automatically!

[image]

What I want is that the collection duplicate to the vertex group and kept the original size 100%.
Even when lately I want to scale the geometry, it still stays in the same target position…
I also uploaded the blender file…I would be appreciated if someone could give me a hint…

Thank you very much in advance!

blender file attached.
[image]

Comment: Apply scale on "Target."

Comment: Thx Nathan, I am not really understand what u mean...
I tried put Target in the Attribute Fill...then nothing happen.

can u pls discribe more explicit...? a screenshot or blender file will help me alot...big thx!

Comment: Select the object that is named "Target".  In object mode, ctrl a -> scale.